# Changing duration of multiple still frames at once (stopmotion animation)

Tags: davinci-resolve, blackmagic

I want to make video from multiple still photos (some kind of slideshow). When I drag&drop photos from media pool, they appear on timeline, but last too long. When I select all frames, press right mouse button and choose "change clip duration" I can set some value. Unfortunately, they are changing duration but stay at previous position leaving some gaps:

[image]

Are there any other ways to set duration of all frames to the same, fixed value (0.5 second for example), and at the same time keep them all together?

Comment: Just a note...in Resolve 15 the path is... Preferences > User > Editing > Standard still duration setting

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Edit** > **Delete Gaps**

This will remove all gaps on all tracks. To exclude a particular track, you can lock the track before you Delete Gaps.

You can also change the default Image/Still duration before the import in the application **Preferences** > **User**  > **General** > **Standard still duration** setting

Comment: thanks! I will try it out today and eventually mark this as best answer